# Python program abort()-ed on normal exit whenever Cython module is imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, abort

Basically, my Python program is behaving as if I called `os.abort()` even though I'm quitting normally with `sys.exit()` (with no parameter).

It's giving me the standard "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way" when the program terminates. It's not *crashing*, (well, unless something's happening inside the shutdown routines, but I don't see any evidence of that) it only terminates when it's supposed to terminate - it just pops up an annoying dialogue box whenever it does so.

I'm using `atexit` for some things but commenting out the hook and the import statement changes nothing. I have a global exception handler around the main loop, but I don't see how that could be it either.

Here's said handler:

```
try:
    while True:
        #...
except Exception:
    if _distributable:
        #Crash reporting! Yay!
        send_error_report("Unhandled exception")
    else:
        raise
```

This happens with regular ol' Python; it happens after being frozen with cx_freeze too, but that can't be the cause because it also happens if I just run the .py script in my IDE.

I use a Cython module for some simple number-crunching, if that might have anything to do with it.

EDIT:

Commenting out the Cython import fixed it. Now I just have to figure out why Cython is causing this...

Here's the Cython code in its entirety:

```
import pygame
cimport numpy
import numpy.random
from libc.stdlib cimport abs

cpdef chromatic_aberration(surface,int intensity=5):
    cdef int x,y,z,maxx,maxy
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=3] array
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=2] r,g,b
    r=pygame.surfarray.pixels_red(surface)
    g=pygame.surfarray.pixels_green(surface)
    b=pygame.surfarray.pixels_blue(surface)
    array=pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(surface)

    maxx,maxy=surface.get_rect().bottomright

    for x in range(maxx):
        for y in range(maxy):
            try:
                pass
                array[x,y,0]=r[x+intensity,y]
                array[x,y,1]=g[x,y+intensity]
                array[x,y,2]=b[x+intensity,y-intensity]
            except IndexError:
                pass

cpdef mapped_chromatic_aberration(surface, numpy.ndarray[int,ndim=2] intensitymap):
    cdef int x,y,z,maxx,maxy,intensity
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=3] array
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=2] r,g,b
    r=pygame.surfarray.pixels_red(surface)
    g=pygame.surfarray.pixels_green(surface)
    b=pygame.surfarray.pixels_blue(surface)
    array=pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(surface)

    maxx,maxy=surface.get_rect().bottomright

    for x in range(maxx):
        for y in range(maxy):
            try:
                intensity=intensitymap[x,y]
                array[x,y,0]=r[x+intensity,y]
                array[x,y,1]=g[x,y+intensity]
                array[x,y,2]=b[x+intensity,y-intensity]
            except IndexError:
                pass

cpdef random_chromatic_aberration(surface,int intensity=5):
    mapped_chromatic_aberration(surface,numpy.random.random_integers(-intensity,intensity,surface.get_rect().bottomright))

cpdef chroma_warp(surface,int x, int y, int radius, int power):
    cdef numpy.ndarray[int,ndim=2] warpmap
    warpmap=numpy.zeros(surface.get_size(), dtype=numpy.int)
    cdef int maxdist = radius ** 2
    cdef int maxx, minx, maxy, miny, warpx, warpy

    for xofst in range(-radius, radius):
        for yofst in range(-radius, radius):
            warpx=x+xofst
            warpy=y+yofst
            warpmap[warpx,warpy] = ((abs(xofst) + abs(yofst)) * power) // 100

    mapped_chromatic_aberration(surface, warpmap)
```

It also doesn't happen if I run the program with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `fx.pyd`, Cython recompiled, and suddenly everything was fine. Must be gremlins.